# Dynamically changing pagination rows value in jsf primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, paginator

I have a situation where I need to persist the value of rows attribute in Datatable and need to change it from the Managed bean. I am currently using jsf 3.4.1.

Consider the sample code below,

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtPaginatorView.cars}" rows="10"
                     paginator="true"
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
```

and I want it to be like...

```
 <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtPaginatorView.cars}" rows="#{dtPaginatorView.rows}"
                     paginator="true"
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
```

so that I can bind the "rows" value to Managed bean variable which I can change it depending on logical conditions. Is it also possible to track the currently selected "rowsPerPageTemplate" value.

Any help into this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing braces around rows="dtPaginatorView.rows" it should be rows="#{dtPaginatorView.rows}" . I do this in all my apps and persist the rows it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it while typing. When I am using braces, value is persisting but pagination is not working. Can you share your example with XHTML file and related managed bean

Answer (score 0):

As per request from OP here is what I do.  I store my rows per user so that way each user of my app can set their own "rows" value and persist it.

**XHTML:**

```
<p:dataTable var="row" 
             rowKey="#{row.id}" filterEvent="enter"
             value="#{auditTrailDatatable.values}"
             filteredValue="#{auditTrailDatatable.filteredValues}" 
              paginatorTemplate="#{appmsg['datatable.paginator']}" 
              paginator="true" 
              rows="#{applicationUser.rowsPerPage}" 
              rowsPerPageTemplate="#{appmsg['datatable.rowsperpage']}">
```

**JPA ENTITY (trimmed for brevity):**

```
public class ApplicationUser  {

   /** How many rows per page to display in datatables */
   @Column(name = "ROWS_PER_PAGE", length = 19, nullable = false)
   @Min(value = 5)
   private Integer rowsPerPage;

   public final Integer getRowsPerPage() {
      return rowsPerPage;
   }

   public final void setRowsPerPage(final Integer rowsPerPage) {
      this.rowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
   }

}
```

**UI PROVIDER:**

```
@SessionScoped
public class ApplicationUserProvider implements Serializable {

   /** Logger for this class */
   private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationUserProvider.class);
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   /** Servlet request for this invocation */
   @Inject
   HttpServletRequest request;

   /** The DAO used to update the local application user entity */
   @Inject
   ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;

   /** State Variable: Cached copy of the current ApplicationUser record */
   private ApplicationUser applicationUser;

   /**
    * Called on user session initialization. Ensures that we have an Application
    * user record for the current user.
    */
   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
      try {
         final Principal currentUser = request.getUserPrincipal();
         final String userName = StringUtils.upperCase(currentUser.getName());

         // attempt to locate our ApplicationUser record for the currently
         // authenticated User
         applicationUser = applicationUserRepository.find(userName);
         if (applicationUser == null) {
            applicationUser = ApplicationUser.createApplicationUser(userName);
            applicationUser.setLastLoginTime(DateTime.now().toDate());
            applicationUserRepository.persist(applicationUser);
         } else {
            applicationUser.setLastLoginTime(DateTime.now().toDate());
            applicationUser = applicationUserRepository.merge(applicationUser);
         }

         LOG.info("User '{}' logged in.", userName);
      } catch (final Exception ex) {
         LOG.error("Unexpected Exception with UserPrincipal: {}", ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(ex), ex);
         throw ex;
      }
   }

   /**
    * The currently logged in {@link ApplicationUser} being provided for
    * injection in other classes and exposed on the UI with @Named.
    *
    * @return the {@link ApplicationUser} object representing the currently
    *         logged in user.
    */
   @Produces
   @Named
   @LoggedIn
   public ApplicationUser getApplicationUser() {
      return applicationUser;
   }

}
```